# Mouse cursor disappears in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, mouse, 15.04, cursor

Recently I installed Kubuntu 15.04 and found that when I'm using Nvidia drivers mouse cursor disappears when I move it to top of the display. It is few pixels "invisible" gap on top. Every other side of display doesn't hide cursor. Running 346.59 version

Edit: found, that it's a bug with Nvidia 346 drivers: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-346/+bug/1440012

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem before in ubuntu. Try this command: 
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false`

and reboot your computer.

Comment: It seems that this command is dedicated for Gnome DE, not for KDE.

Comment: Besides you don't need a full reboot after such command. Just logging out and back in should be enough if it doesn't take effect immediately.